# How do I add a Smart App Banner of my Android App which is not listed on Playstore to my website

Tags: html, css, smartbanner

Guys I am not from the field of computers , so please pardon me if I sound silly ,I am basically a mechanical engineer and a writer and I have my Poetry Website on Blogger of which I have made an Android App which is not listed on Playstore , although I have that APK file uploaded on my Google Drive ,and thus I want the visitors of my website to download my Android App that I have uploaded over my Google Drive , I want to make my Google Drive open sharing link of the APK file as my smart URL or so ,So as to create an App Banner for my App.Hope you might have understood what I wanted to convey and if it's possible please guide me how ? , and please provide the code for that if possible.

Thanks in Advance 
You are Awesome

Comment: No, I didn't understand you. You want to let your users download the APK file from your GDrive account? Just provide a public link to it.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply mate ... yeah that I know brother and I have that public link .... I just want to make a smart app banner using that link ... so that users can get the option to download the app or else cancel .